# Bash find return value

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to find a file and am checking in multiple locations, but instead of just finding it and moving on I would like to know exactly where it is. Does "find" return a value other than what is passed to the find query? If it finds something does it also return true or 0?

```
FILE="file.txt"
DIR1="/path1/"
DIR2="/path2/"
```

I know this is syntactically incorrect but what I need is something like...

```
if ${DIR1}${FILE} = true
then
    echo "${FILE} has been found in ${DIR1}"
fi
```

Is there something better than find to use here?

Comment: if file are located in one level from your current working directory, you could `ls */file.ext` or if any fixed number of sublevel: `ls */*/*/file.ext`. Using *curses* and *interactive bash*, you could hit: `anyCommand */*/file.ext` **but no [return]**, instead, hit `[tab]` consecutively two time. The console would display possible completions, but notting is run.

Answer (score 2):

How about the unix `find` tool?

```
FILE="file.txt"
DIR1="/path1/"
DIR2="/path2/"

find "$DIR1" "$DIR2" -type f -name "$FILE"
```

This prints a file path to `stdout` for each file found.

**Explanation:**

- `find` - invoke `find`, look for files recursively
- `"$DIR1" "$DIR2"` - specify the list of directory paths to look under
- `-type f` - consider only files (not directories, links)
- `-name "$FILE"` - specify the name of the file.

Comment: `find` returns success status even if nothing is found.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your directories in an array then loop through the array and test if the files exist:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="file.txt"
DIR1="/path1/"
DIR2="/path2/"
DIRS=(DIR1 DIR2) 

for dir in ${DIRS[*]}
do
   if [ -e $FILE ]
   then
      echo "File " $FILE " exists in directory " $dir
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

simpler and quicker than "find" is "locate".

```
locate -b file.txt
```

This will tell where file.txt is located.

Locate has a indexed database of files and directories, so it is quicker. However find is more powerful and is useful in cases of piping commands or doing other advanced things.

If you want to check file existence for conditional execution, check out this link:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Answer (score 0):

Another version of @McMillen's answer, just a little bit shorter and potentially not so readable:

```
[[ -e ${DIR}${FILE} ]] && echo "$FILE has been found in ${DIR}"
```

The first part checks the existence of FILE in DIR and only if it succeeds (&&) , the `echo` part is run